# How to get jinja2 to raise an error when a {% trans %} tag isn't replaced with anything

Tags: django, internationalization, jinja2

I'm using django & jinja2 templates for an internationalized website.

In debug mode, I'd like Jinja2 to throw an error when it fails to find a translation for a string marked with

```
{% trans %}abc{% endtrans %}
```

Setting it to raise errors when variables were not found in templates helped to find a bunch of problems, and I think this would help with preventing accidentally breaking a translation string, too.